# Associate the object property name with other value

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types, javascript-objects

I have a class to create an object
I have another class that uses this class in its constructor and some types:

```
import {makeAutoObservable, makeObservable, runInAction} from "mobx";
import {MainStore} from "./MainStore";

export const enum SystemColumnsName {
    STATUS = 'Статус',
}
type SystemColumnsType = {
    [key: string]: SystemColumn;
};

class SystemColumn {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly referencePath: string;
    public isActive: boolean;
    constructor(item_key: string, name: string, referencePath: string, isActive: boolean) {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
        this.id = item_key;
        this.name = name;
        this.referencePath = referencePath;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }
}


export class ViewStore {
    public systemColumns: SystemColumnsType = {};
    private _mainStore: MainStore;

    constructor(mainStore: MainStore) {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
        this._mainStore = mainStore;
        this.systemColumns[SystemColumnsName.STATUS] = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', SystemColumnsName.STATUS, 'statusColumn', true);
        this.systemColumns[SystemColumnsName.STATUS] = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', SystemColumnsName.STATUS, 'statusColumn', true);
        this.systemColumns[SystemColumnsName.STATUS] = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', SystemColumnsName.STATUS, 'statusColumn', true);
        this.systemColumns[SystemColumnsName.STATUS] = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', SystemColumnsName.STATUS, 'statusColumn', true);
        this.systemColumns[SystemColumnsName.STATUS] = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', SystemColumnsName.STATUS, 'statusColumn', true);
    }
    public setSystemColumnStatus(systemColumnKey: string, isActive: boolean) {
        this.systemColumns[systemColumnKey].isActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

now, when setting the property of an object, I can create many objects of the same type and assign to the same property:

```
this.systemColumns[SystemColumnsName.STATUS] = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', SystemColumnsName.STATUS, 'statusColumn', true);
```

that now the compiler does not swear:
the question is: how to achieve a prohibition of such behavior through types, and achieve a connection between: SystemColumnsName.STATUS?

```
this.systemColumns **[SystemColumnsName.STATUS]** = new SystemColumn('systemsStatusItem', **SystemColumnsName.STATUS**, 'statusColumn', true);
```

how to force the TS to throw an error if a similar property already exists in the object?

Answer (score 0):

Create a utility method to constrain the key and `name` to be of the same value.

```js
private setSystemColumn(itemKey: string, name: SystemColumnsName, referencePath: string, isActive: boolean): void {
  if (this.systemColumns[name] instanceof SystemColumn) {
    // to throw if this property already exists
    throw new Error();
  }

  this.systemColumns[name] = new SystemColumn(itemKey, name, referencePath, isActive);
}
```